# Why can't my user (author) login from back-end to post article in Joomla

Tags: authentication, joomla

I have just created a new user from my administrator back-end. I have assigned this user to groups like author and publisher. But this user can't seem to login to the admin screen to create articles.

I don't want to give this user high privileges.  Am I missing something? How can my user do this?

BTW, I don't have a login page in the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default log in to the Joomla back-end is disabled for `Registered`, `Author`, `Editor` and `Publisher` groups (it's inherited from a `Public` group for which this action is not defined, and therefore is prohibited).

Select **Allowed** for **Admin Login** action in **Global Configuration -> Permission Settings** to the desired group.